# Spying on a method parameters in phpunit, while calling the original method

Tags: phpunit

I am trying to understand is it possible with phpunit to create spy on a method, while calling the original method.

I have done it in java, but I don't see a way to do it in phpunit. I only find that if I spy on the invocations of the method, I also need to mock it.

Example code:

```
            $this->spy = $this->getMockBuilder('\ClassUnderTest')
                ->setMethods(['methodToSpy'])
                ->getMock();            

            $this->spy->expects($this->any())
                    ->method('methodToSpy')
                    ->will($this->returnCallback(array($this, 'stubMethodToSpy')));
```

So in the test, I want to "spy" on the call to the real method 'methodToSpy()', so I can make on-the-fly analysis on the parameters passed to it (I need to use them in the test later on).

Any idea if this is possible? (or maybe it is not possible in phpunit because it is not multithreaded like java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [test proxies](https://thephp.cc/news/2014/03/phpunit-4-0-test-proxies).

Comment: I am trying to use "enableProxyingToOriginalMethods" as you suggested. Is it possible to 'listen' to one method, but to mock another? Whenever I use it together with SetMethods I get errors..

Comment: Real stubbing/mocking and proxying cannot be mixed.

Comment: Doesn't seem to allow proxying some methods but not all of them.